# Mongoose .findByIdAndUpdate not updating record

Tags: mongoose

I have an express route using mongoose. This .findByIdAndUpdate isn't working. I see the "removeId" come in, the second console.log shows the correct record... but it didn't update! Am I doing something wrong here?

```
router.post('/highlight', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    const { removeId, addId } = req.body; 
    console.log('removeId', removeId)
    Article
        .findByIdAndUpdate(removeId, {
            featured: false
        })
        .then(updatedArticle => {
            console.log('updated article', updatedArticle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a strange default but [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) doesn't return the updated record by default. You have to pass {new:true} to get it.

```
router.post('/highlight', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    const { removeId, addId } = req.body; 
    console.log('removeId', removeId)
    Article
        .findByIdAndUpdate(removeId,{new: true}, {
            featured: false
        })
        .then(updatedArticle => {
            console.log('updated article', updatedArticle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb `findOneAndUpdate` method has an option called `returnNewDocument` which as per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/):

> **Optional**. When true, returns the **updated document** instead of the
>   original document. Defaults to **false**.

Mongoose wraps that method but it calls its pass through option `new` as per its [code/documentation](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/750f399ed9d7684bdeca659bb294561c12678865/lib/model.js#L2216):

```
outer.post('/highlight', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  const { removeId, addId } = req.body; 
  console.log('removeId', removeId)
  return Article.findByIdAndUpdate(removeId, {featured: false}, {new: true})
    .then(updatedArticle =>
       console.log('updated article', updatedArticle)
    )   
})
```

Also do not forget the `return` your `Article.findByIdAndUpdate` in your post method.